# Is there an equivalent to React's useId hook in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, react-hooks, vuejs3

In React there is a really handy hook called `useId` that helps ensure HTML IDs are unique across the DOM. I'm wondering if there's anything similar in the Vue ecosystem?

https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useId

Answer (score 6):

Vue doesn't have a public counterpart, and it can be seen that it has been just recently become available in React.

It can be done in Vue by using internal API that is frequently used in existing third-party libraries and unlikely to break:

```
const uid = getCurrentInstance().uid;
```

Or by using any unique id generator with global state like Lodash:

```
const uid = _.uniqueId();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Vue` is going to introduce it in `v3.5`.

See here: [Vue GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/557)